# Rotate a linked list k times (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list

While practicing for my final in Python programming I ran into this question "def rotaten" of rotating k times. The problem says that k can range from 0 to any positive integer number (even greater than list size, if k < 0 raise ValueError
and it must execute in O( (n-k)%n ) where n is the length of the list. It also has the following warnings:

- WARNING: DO *NOT* call .rotate() k times !!!!
- WARNING: DO *NOT* try to convert whole linked list to a python list
- WARNING: DO *NOT* swap node data or create nodes
  The problem is that I'm not understanding the solution given. Is there an easier way to solve this problem? Thank you in advance

```
class Node:
   
    def __init__(self,initdata):
        self._data = initdata
        self._next = None

    def get_data(self):
        return self._data

    def get_next(self):
        return self._next

    def set_data(self,newdata):
        self._data = newdata

    def set_next(self,newnext):
        self._next = newnext


class LinkedList:
    def rotaten(self, k):
        
        if k < 0:
            raise ValueError
        
        if self._size > 1:
            m = k % self._size 
        
        if m > 0 and m < self._size:
            current = self._head
            for i in range(self._size - m - 1):
                current = current.get_next() 
                chain_b = current.get_next() 
                old_head = self._head
                old_last = self._last
                self._last = current 
                self._last.set_next(None) 
                self._head = chain_b 
                old_last.set_next(old_head)
```

Answer (score 0):

### The easiest ways are forbidden

1. warning forbids implementing the singular rotation, then calling it repeatedly
2. warning forbids using native python structure - python has list built-in in basic collections `list()`, which can be then transformed to a `deque`, which can then be rotated by popping from the end and inserting the same node to the beginning.
3. warning is preventing you from making your life easier by creating some other nodes or worse - copying data. (copying data from one node to another would remove any advantage you had from storing the data into the lists in the first place)

The example solution is basically this:

- Take the current first node(head of the list) and the tail node which is stored in the List structure. (the bookkeeping of the example list consists of holding the head and tail, the rest is done in the nodes themselves)
- Find the k-th node - so that you rotate the whole list at once. This is where the list needs to be cut.
- Add the last node as the new head, doing all the necessary reference-linking and unlinking. (Which is I guess the point of this question - to test if you understand the references. In C these would be pointers, python has the references implicitly.)

So as far as the linked lists go, this is the most straightforward solution with the requested 
 `O((n-k)%n)` complexity.

Good luck with your pointers :-).